# Opening folder on classpath

Tags: java, file, io, inputstream

So say I have a folder in my project under `com/game/me/resources/thisFolder` and I want to access `thisFolder` to open it and view all the files. Can I do this with Java's `File` class?  These files will need to be access when the project is compiled into a Jar, and I don't know the file names inside the folder. All I will know is where the folder is located within the Jar. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a right (or intended) way to do this since all of this is under a layer of abstraction in the form of the [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). If you know the location of the jar file, you could just treat it as a zip file and open it with the [ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class, but this would be a major hack.

Since you are providing the jar file in the first place, you might as well pack a list of your files from the beginning.

Comment: I can't pack a list because I'm not the one who will be using this. It needs to be abstract just like my question stated.

Comment: Then I see no other way than to open the jar file manually. You should be able to get its location (classpath) from the [System properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).